# if $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)=0$ then f is bounded, for a holomorphic function $f$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I would like to ask you for some help, I have a doubt that I have not been able to solve yet...

let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function.
if $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)=0$ then $f$ is bounded

I don't know yet if this is true, however this is what I have been trying to solve it.

Suppose that $f$ is not bounded, then
\begin{align*}
\forall r>0 : \exists z_r\in\mathbb{C} : f(z_r)\not\in B(0,r) 
\end{align*}
iff
\begin{align*}
\forall r>0  : r\leq|f(z_r)|
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\infty=\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}r\leq\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}|f(z_r)|
\end{align*}

This would be complete provided that $|z_r|\rightarrow\infty$ However, I believe that what I have written is not necessarily true.

If someone could give me some guidance it would be great.

Comment: Hint: if not, then think of the extreme value theorem

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic. $\implies |f|$ is continuous. Now note that real valued continuous functions attain their maximum values on compact sets (in your case it could be a closed ball centered at the origin).

Comment: So you could just weaken your hyptheses to '$f$ is continuous'. This won't require any complex analysis tools. But with the hypotheses you have: $f$ is holomorphic, you could do much more i.e., you could prove $f$ to be a constant map. This follows from Liouville's theorem.

Comment: You are right that $z_r$ need not go to $\infty$ as $r\to \infty$.

Comment: @Koro  I am having difficulty testing it. I have come to  $\forall z\in \overline{B(0,r)} : |f(z_r)|\leq|f(z)|\leq|f(w_r)|$, where $z_r,w_r\in\overline{B(0,r)}$, and $r>0$.

I guess this is where I should use the hypothesis of $\lim |f(z)|=0$ for  $|z|\rightarrow \infty$. 


However, it is still not clear to me.

Comment: I think you're complicating this more than necessary. Try using peek-a-boo's hint: what does the definition of $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} f(z) = 0$ provide you? (Also you need the modulus since complex numbers can't really "tend to infinity")

Comment: $f$ is an entire function with $\infty$ as removable singularity, hence $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 6):

Since $\lim_{z\to \infty}|f(z)|=0$, there exists $R>0$ such that $|z|>R\implies |f(z)|<1$

$|f|$ is continuous on compact  set $\overline{ B(0, R)}$ so attains a maximum $M\ge0$.

$|f|$ is bounded by $\max(M, 1)$.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, you are absolutely right. 

Just one comment; I think you have a little mistake:



you have $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}$  instead of $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty}$.

But regardless of this, it follows the test perfectly, I thank you.

Comment: @F.R. I'm glad that you found it helpful. You are right about the limit, I have fixed it now. Thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: and what can we say about bounded entire functions?

Comment: @robjohn: that they are constant by Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially Koro's argument but with some details.

$\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}f(z)=0$ means that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists and $M$ such that for all $|z|>M$, $|f(z)|<\epsilon$. So, fix, say, $\epsilon=1$. Then, there exists an $M$ such that for all $|z|>M$,  $|f(z)|<1$. But what about when $|z|\leq M$? Well, in which case, we are looking at the closed ball $B^c(0,M)$. Since closed balls are compact ( in $\mathbb{C}$), and that $f$ is continuous, then so is $|f|$. Hence, $|f|$ attains its maximum on $B^c(0,M)$. In other words, there exists a $L$ such that if $|z|\leq M$ then $|f(z)|\leq L$. Hence the maximum of $L$ and 1 gives you the desired bound